# 2000 Chevy Trailblazer Engine Shuts Off When Brake Is On

Tags: engine, chevrolet

I have a 2000 Chevy Trailblazer with 156k miles.
Within the last month when at a stoplight or stop sign or even when I hit the brake backing into the driveway, the car's engine will shutoff. The only way to fix is to put the car in park and then turn the engine back on turning the key in the ignition. The problem does not happen all the time, which is making it frustrating and harder to diagnose.

I've been two different mechanics, both who have had the car for over a week. Neither one had the issue happen to them while driving it. They both checked for error codes, none appeared on the engine, gas pump, nothing. One mech did a smoke test and found some leaks which he fixed, but the problem still occurs.

The car run great otherwise. No check engine lights or other apparent issues. Battery is 3 months old. Had a good tune up in last 2 months with no major issues.

Any idea what this could be? It's my wife's primary car so I'm concerned about her driving it since we don't know what's causing this.

Comment: have you checked for any wires being damaged / chafed by the brake pedal or linkage?

Comment: Have them clean the throttle plate.

Comment: Solar Mike and Moab - will have my mechanic check all. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Some more detail: Was driving it this weekend and the issue happened twice. 

I was braking at a stop light when the engine went dead, the battery light came on, the dashboard lights stayed on and the power steering died also. Had to come to a complete stop, put the car in park and then turn the engine back on with the key.